# How can you override Mage_Adminhtml_Permissions_UserController

Tags: magento-1.9, php

Most of today I have been trying to override Mage controller and I have no ideas what I'm doing wrong. Does anyone can help me.

app/code/local/Fox/Extacl/etc/config.xml

```
<modules>
    <Fox_Extacl>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Fox_Extacl>
</modules>
<global>
    <models>
        <admin>
            <rewrite>
                <session>Fox_Extacl_Model_Session</session>
            </rewrite>
        </admin>
    </models>
    <blocks>
        <adminhtml>
            <rewrite>
                <permissions_user_edit_tab_roles>Fox_Extacl_Block_Permissions</permissions_user_edit_tab_roles>
            </rewrite>
        </adminhtml>
    </blocks>
</global>
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Fox_extacl before="Mage_Adminhtml">Fox_Extacl_Adminhtml</Fox_extacl>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

app/code/local/Fox/Extacl/controllers/Adminhtml/UserController.php

```
<?php 
require_once('/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Permissions/UserController.php');
class Fox_Extacl_Adminhtml_UserController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{

public function saveAction()
{
    if ($data = $this->getRequest()->getPost()) {
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($data);

    }
    // $this->_redirect('*/*/');
}
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First change this from `config.xml`

```
<Fox_extacl before="Mage_Adminhtml">Fox_Extacl_Adminhtml</Fox_extacl>
```

to

```
<Fox_Extacl before="Mage_Adminhtml">Fox_Extacl_Adminhtml</Fox_Extacl>
```

Now here is how the controller rewrite work.
You requested `admin/permissions_user/something`.
Magento looks in all the folders mapped to the adminhtml router for this file  `Permissions/UserController.php`.
So in your case, you need to place the file in `app/code/local/Fox/Extacl/controllers/Adminhtml/Permissions/UserController.php`. You are missing the `Permissions` folder.
And since you are extending a controller and not replacing it, you should make your class extend the original controller.

```
require_once '/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Permissions/UserController.php';
class Fox_Extacl_Adminhtml_Permissions_UserController 
    extends Mage_Adminhtml_Permissions_UserController 
{...}
```

Comment: It did worked! Thank you very much!
Maybe wort of mentioning I have also change the require_once path to:  
`require_once '/var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Permissions/UserController.php'`;

Answer (score 1):

Since your trying to put your module before Adminhtml

Try

```
require_once('/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Permissions/UserController.php');
class Fox_Extacl_Adminhtml_Permissions_UserController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Permissions_UserController
{
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to rename your Controller to UserController.

This controller should listen to the route:

```
/<whateverYourAdminDirIs>/extacl/
```